# Extracting images from HTML with HTMLReader library on Objective-C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, parsing

I am an Objective C beginner and currently building an iOS app that extracts images from HTML pages just like Pinterest.

By searching through stack overflow, I found HTMLReader was recommended by many to parse HTML, so I installed it.

However, there is not so much of documents on the web that explain about how to use this library except for the sample code on the github page.
Could anyone advise me of how to extract image URLs from web pages using HTMLReader?
Below is what I tried.

**Objective-C Code**

```
NSString * htmlBody = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                       @"document.body.innerHTML"];
HTMLDocument *document = [HTMLDocument documentWithString:htmlBody];
NSLog(@"%@", [document firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"img src"].textContent);
```

**Sample web URL I tried to parse**

http://www.lifehack.org/articles/lifestyle/100-life-hacks-that-make-life-easier.html

**Expected Outcome on the console**

http://cdn-media-1.lifehack.org/wp-content/files/2014/09/US_map_-_states-370x208.png 
(since it is the first image that comes up when I search for "src img" on this site)

**Actual Outcome I got**

(Null)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
HTMLElement *element = [document firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"img"];
```

To get the image url, you just have to access the HTMLElement's attributes NSDictionary, and get the object for key "src":

```
NSString *urlString = element.attributes["src"];
```

Comment: How do you get the absolute url from that?